# Deligne's proof of Ramanujan's conjecture

Tags: modular-forms, ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives

I am trying to understand Deligne's proof of the Ramanujan conjecture and more generally how one associates geometric objects (ultimately, motives) to modular forms.

As the first step, which I understand more or less, one identifies the space of cusp forms $S_k(\Gamma)$ with the first cohomology group $W$ of $X(\Gamma)$ with coefficients in some sheaf (Deligne calls W parabolic cohomology). If we assume the weight is equal to 2, then this parabolic cohomology would probably just become $H^1(X(\Gamma), \mathbb C)$.

After that point I unfortunately understand practically nothing in Deligne's paper (modular forms and l-adic cohomology), so maybe someone could give an informal explanation:

1. What are the next steps in order to identify the Dirichlet series corresponding to a cusp form $f$ with a Hasse-Weil series of a motive (is this what we are doing?)
2. Also, what role does the Hecke action play here (in particular, how is some adelic gadget that Deligne calls the Hecke action related to the usual one)?
3. And what role does the field $\mathbb Q_f$ constructed by adjoining the coefficients of $f$ play?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A correction and a comment. The correction: need to take direct sum of $S_k(\Gamma)$ and its conjugate twist to get degree-1 parabolic cohomology of a suitable $(k-2)$th symmetric-power sheaf on the "open" modular curve $Y(\Gamma)$.  (For $k=2$, this asserts the Hodge decomposition of ${\rm{H}}^1(X(\Gamma),\mathbf{C})$ and its identification with "parabolic cohomology" of $Y(\Gamma)$.) The comment: it is for questions like this where you should call upon your good fortune to be at a department where there are faculty who can explain the whole story to you in person. 

Comment: To amplify on BCnrd's comment: at Northwestern, you should direct such questions to Calegari and/or Emerton.  

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deligne's construction works as follows. He identifies the space $GL_2(\mathbb{A})/GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ with the $\mathbb{C}$-points of the variety* $\mathcal{M}_{ell,level}$ parameterizing elliptic curves with complete level structure, or equivalently, the moduli space of elliptic curves up to isogeny with complete (in the appropriately modified sense) level structure. The latter perspective has the advantage that there's an obvious $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$-action. Furthermore, this moduli perspective has the advantage that both the variety and this action are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since this action is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, there are commuting (!) actions of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q})$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$ on the (e.g., parabolic, with coefficients in $Sym^k$ of the Tate module of the tautological elliptic curves) cohomology of $\mathcal{M}_{ell,level}$. Therefore, for a prime $p$, there are commuting actions of the Hecke algebra at $p$ on the $G(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-invariants and the Galois group. Running this over all primes over which your eigenform $f$ is unramified, you get a commuting action of a big Hecke algebra and the Galois group. Finally, $f$ determines a maximal ideal of this big Hecke algebra being an eigenform, so you can take the "$f$-isotypic" component of this cohomology.

The first theorem of Eichler and Shimura tells you that this isotypic component has dimension $2$. Then the Eichler-Shimura relation tells you that the Hecke-eigenvalues correspond to the traces of Frobenius as predicted by Langlands et al. This matching of eigenvalues/traces of Frobenius exactly means that the L-function of this modular form match the Artin L-function of the representation.

Deligne also gives a modular-type description of the action of these Hecke operators because knowing that the Hecke operators are given by correspondences (so within the world of motives) allows him to apply the Weil conjectures on how e.g. constant sheaves behave under motivic-type operations. From here he deduces the Ramanujan conjecture.

* Actually, it's somewhat better to think of it as a provariety. Then notions of compactly supported etale cohomology are actually defined, and from this perspective cohomology of $Sym^k$ of the tautological $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-sheaf on this space given as the $\ell$-adic Tate module of the canonical elliptic curve (which is trivial on the variety) is not just the direct sum of $k+1$ copies of cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$.

Comment: Thanos, your "*" is very cryptic. Also, may be good to indicate where the hard work lies (to see why Serre couldn't write the Bourbaki report).  Eichler-Shimura relation doesn't tell what you say; e.g., Deligne's treatment of $\Delta$ is too easy because it spans space of forms at its wt any level. Need duality arguments & *bad reduction* information (+SGA1, XIII!) in general. Also, application of RH is much harder than you indicate because need to find a compactified resolution of singularities in char > 0 (now moot thanks to Weil II...). That is one of the most novel things in the report. 

Comment: 1. Is there an easy way to see why GL(A)-action must be related to Hecke-correspondeces action?

Comment: 2. Also, what does "Big Hecke algebra" mean?

Comment: 3. What is "f-isotypic"?

Comment: 4. "The first theorem of Eichler and Shimura tells you that this isotypic component has dimension 2"
Is it because the space of weight 12 forms is 1-dimensional? 

Comment: 5. After the Dirichlet series is identified with the Artin L-series of the Galois representation W, what makes it possible to use Weil conjectures? Will this L-series be a factor in the Hasse-Weil zeta function of M, because W is a "piece" of cohomology of M?

Comment: Dear BCnrd: * means: a person might do a stupider construction wherein you take cohomology of Sym^k of the Tate module over the moduli space of ell. curves with complete lvl str. However, this is a trivial module, Sym^k is just a direct sum of trivials.... Instead, Deligne takes limits of cohomologies over moduli with finite lvl str, and this gives something more non-trivial. One is naturally led to this def'n by thinking of the space as a pro-variety. Also, I have some queasiness about cptly supported cohomology on infinite type varieties (i.e., Nagata doesn't go through....).

Comment: ... All your points are fair, especially that I left out the bad reduction information which is needed to match numbers at every prime instead of almost every prime. I did intend to describe Deligne's construction in a post-Weil II world. But perhaps one piece of hard work for this theorem you are not emphasising either: the Weil conjectures!

Comment: Evgeny, I again repeat my initial advice: talk to Matt or Frank (or Toby if he's there yet).  You have a large number of basic questions, which are all quite reasonable, but asking them all here is not an efficient way to get the answers at a level of specificity which you seek. 

Comment: Dear Evgeny:
1. I know it by a computation. Maybe someone else here knows a conceptual explanation. 
2. A restricted tensor product of Hecke algebras over many primes.
3. f determines a character of an algebra acting on this space. You can take the piece of this space on which the algebra acts with character "f".
4. I meant the Shimura isomorphism. You don't need Delta for this: it works for any cusp form.
5. The representation W comes from geometry: it's cptly supported cohomology with coefficients in push-forwards from proper things. Weil conjectures are about eigenvalues of Frob. on these.

Comment: Thanos, Deligne's article was written some years before RH was proved. To *rigorously* reduce Ramanujan to RH was quite something.  My comment about "bad reduction information" had to do with rigorous arguments for *good* primes: if one does proof that Hecke eigenvalue relates to a Frobenius trace (esp. for weight > 2) for good primes, one has to confront the fact that the "middle" object in the $p$th Hecke correspondence is a modular curve with $p$ in level, and one is trying to work mod $p$! That bad reduction, and cohom. base change problems, are serious tasks which "philosophy" hides.  

Comment: Brian, thank you for your advise. However, first of all I am not at Northwestern right now. Moreover, I feel more comfortable asking questions here, since this way I am not wasting anybody's time -  only the people who are willing to answer will do so. Also, in this particular case since I gave up 500 points of my reputation for this question, I thought Thanos wouldn't mind claryfing his answer. 

Comment: Evgeny, fair point (on the location issue). This is the kind of very very long mathematical story which is really hard to communicate through a medium like MO.  Let's see what Thanos decides to put in writing here...

Comment: @Brian: Thank you for clarifying. It's true that I'm failing to mention any of a large number of serious technical issues, only, Weil II and the Ramanujan conjecture are a long and complicated story, so I've found it useful to have a vague exposition like the above in mind. But, again, yes, pirate-treasure-map expositions will have massive holes :)!
@Evgeny: I don't mind having to clarify my answers.