# The connection between the Weil conjectures and Ramanujan's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, riemann-hypothesis, weil-conjectures

I'm writing an essay about Ramanujan's conjecture and have some questions:

1 How is Ramanujan's conjecture connected with the Weil conjectures?

2 How could Ramanujan's conjecture be assumed true or deduced when Deligne proved the Weil conjecture?

3 How Is Ramanujan's conjecture connected or equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

4 Are there any good articles on these subjects?

Thanks ann regards.

Comment: there are many expositions, which may or may not be suitable for your intended audience; I liked a recent article by [Frans Oort](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2014-15-3-211.pdf)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks, I have also found this article and really liked it

Comment: @CarloBeenakker the article says 'The answer
is negative in the strict sense: there is no implication
pRH ⇒ RH (and also no argument the
reverse way)' what does negative in strict sense mean?

Comment: the answer refers to the question: "Does this [pRH] provide any progress for the solution of the classical RH?" So "negative in a strict sense" means there is no logical implication, but one cannot exclude that progress has been made in a wider sense.

Comment: There is a book draft by Brian Conrad on this topic and generalizations: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edix/public_html_rennes/brian.ps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, the coefficients of an holomorphic cusp form are related to the number of points on a certain smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and the Weil-Riemann hypothesis gives the neccesary error term for the number of points. This is the content of

- Pierre Deligne, "[Formes modulaires et représentations l-adiques](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1968-1969__11__139_0.pdf)" (1969)

The Riemann hypothesis over finite fields was of course proved later by Deligne in his "[Weil I](http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1974__43__273_0.pdf)" paper.

I'm not sure what the best place to learn these things is (I mean the Ramanujan conjecture, conditionally on the Weil conjecture; for the later there are plenty of resources, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/114034)), other than Deligne's paper, but can find some information here on MO,

- [Deligne's proof of Ramanujan's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30527)
- [Reference request for a proof of Ramanujan's tau conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/19169)

As for you third question, there seems to be no relationship between Ramanujan-type conjectures and the location of zeros inside the critical strip, whether you are considering the L-funcion attached to a modular form, or any other L-function of arithmetic or geometric origin.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that Ramanujan's tau function also had a critical strip of non-trivial zeroes, or at least it's L-function, but I may misinterpreted that

Comment: @ziermensch: Yes, the tau function has an $L$-function. When you properly normalize (define) it, it has a functional equation relating $s$ to $1-s$, and the non-trivial zeros lie in the critical strip $0<\Re(s)<1$. On the other hand, the Ramanujan conjecture has not helped us so far to understand these zeros. There are certain properties of $L$-functions where it helps to know that the coefficients satisfy the Ramanujan conjecture, but the Riemann hypothesis lies pretty far from them (as far as we know).

Comment: @GHfromMO okay, Thanks I understand it now! :)

Comment: Ramanujan-type results _do_ give the best possible half-plane of absolute convergence of the $L$-function and Euler product corresponding to a modular form. But, in effect, this just gets us to the _edge_ of the critical strip, just as we know that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Of course! Thanks for pointing it out. I was thinking only about the critical strip, I'll edit.